# KeyError: "['SALINITY;PSU'] not in index"

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have this code to process CTD data, it's working normally until I try to process the salinity column, giving me this error:

KeyError: "['SALINITY;PSU'] not in index"

But when I check the columns it's all there, here is the code`

```
df = pd.read_csv('/home/labdino/PycharmProjects/CTDprocessing/venv/DadosCTD_tabulacao.csv',
                 sep='\t',
                 skiprows=header,
                 )
down, up = df.split()
```

```
down = down[["TEMPERATURE;C", "SALINITY;PSU"]]

process = (down.remove_above_water()
           .remove_up_to(idx=7)
           .despike(n1=2, n2=20, block=100)
           .lp_filter()
           .press_check()
           .interpolate()
           .bindata(delta=1, method="average")
           .smooth(window_len=21, window="hanning")
           )

process.head()
```

`
Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/labdino/PycharmProjects/CTDprocessing/venv/CTDLab.py", line 47, in <module>
    down = down[["TEMPERATURE;C", "SALINITY;PSU"]]
  File "/home/labdino/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3811, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns._get_indexer_strict(key, "columns")[1]
  File "/home/labdino/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 6108, in _get_indexer_strict
    self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
  File "/home/labdino/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 6171, in _raise_if_missing
    raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")
KeyError: "['SALINITY;PSU'] not in index"
```

When I use this code with any other column it works, but when trying with salinity it doesn't, and I checked the csv file and it's all normal.

Comment: You might want to check the `skiprows=header` line

Comment: I deleted the header and tried to run it again and I get the same error